# selectpicker : Get the data attribute of selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select, bootstrap-selectpicker

I'm having hard time in to getting the data attribute set to select option on bootstrap selectpicker .

I tried:

```
$('.selectpicker').on('changed.bs.select', function (e) {
    var selected = e.target.value;
    console.log("value :  ", selected ); // gives selected value
    console.log("data attribute:  ", $(e.target).data("price")); 
});
```

data attribute always returns **undefined**

what wrong I'm doing here ?

Comment: Could be several things from `e.target` not being what you expect, `console.log(e.target)` to confirm, or the element doesn't have the attribute assigned, spelled or specified as you expect. Please post the actual markup of the relevant DOM in a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) using the code snipped feature.

Comment: exactly wich line return undefined ? Please, make a fiddle that reproduces the error.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This works.

```
$('.selectpicker').on("changed.bs.select", function() {
    var dataTypeAttribute = $('option:selected', this).attr("data-type");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just specify id to select

```
$("#selectidhere").on("change", function () {
  var dataname = $("option[value=" + $(this).val() + "]", this).attr('data-name');
  alert(dataname);
});
```

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/v7naao59/849/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.selectpicker').on('changed.bs.select', function (e) {
var selected = e.target.value;
console.log("value :  "+selected ); // gives selected value
console.log("data attribute:  "+$(e.target).attr("data-price"));});
```

Comment: It would help to call out what you are providing here, it looks like your only change is "data" to "data-price", as the change from commas to string concat isn't going to change the logs. So would explain why your answers solves the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".selectpicker").on("changed.bs.select", 
    function(e, clickedIndex, isSelected, oldValue) {
        var arrayOfSelected = $('.selectpicker').eq(0).val();
        console.log(arrayOfSelected);
 });
```

It looks weird but it works perfectly so I don't care.